# re.split returns empty string when split at a digit

Tags: python-2.7

```
import re

s = 'name1000'

n = re.split(('\d+'), s)

print(n)
```

The output is `['name', '']`.

I don't know why am I getting an empty `string` at the second position and not the number '1000'.

Comment: The "1000" is what you split on. The only parts left are "name" and "".

Answer (score 0):

Because you are splitting a string using any sequence of digits as the separator. If your string was `'name1000name'` your response would be `['name', 'name']`.

Answer (score -1):

There is a mistake in our regex. A solution is :

```
n = re.split('(\d+)', s)
```